# javascript dot notation to bracket notation in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I'm looking to use google closure. I need to convert some dot notation to bracket notation.

At the moment, I'm accessing properties in a loop like this:

```
TheArray[i].MyProp1;
TheArray[i].MyProp2;
```

When I write

```
TheArray[i].['MyProp1'];
```

it doesn't convert. How do I do this conversion to bracket notation in arrays of objects.

Comment: This issue comes up about 100x per day, there *has* to be a resource online that can properly describe the array-access concept to beginners.

Comment: @zzzzBov: yea, I seo'ed the question's URL. Should be fixed:) You can upvote the question if you want to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the dot.

It should just be `TheArray[i]['MyProp1'];`

Answer (score 0):

The brackets directly translate to the dot notation - you're accessing a member of the object.

```
TheArray[i]['MyProp1']
```